# Symfony 6 EasyAdmin 4 ImageField value Empty and path problem

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin, symfony6

Using EasyAdmin 4 on Symfony 6, I have 2 problems with the ImageField.

Problem 1:

The field has no value on forms even when the field has a value in the database. This results in a validation error when I try to update an existing "Camp".

[image: Missing value]

Problem 2:

The upload works, but it doesn't create directories when using setUploadedFileNamePattern with slashes.

[image: missing date parts from directory structure]

### UPDATE

I found out that if I'm using a file name pattern without slashes, it works. So the question is how can I get it to work with slashes as it is shown in the docs https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields/ImageField.html#setuploadedfilenamepattern.

It works with

```
yield ImageField::new('...')->setUploadedFileNamePattern('[slug]-[contenthash].[extension]');
```

but doesn't work with

```
yield ImageField::new('...')->setUploadedFileNamePattern('[year]/[month]/[day]/[slug]-[contenthash].[extension]');
```

Here is the code.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CampRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ORM\Table(name: 'camps')]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CampRepository::class)]
class Camp
{
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'cid')]
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'IDENTITY')]
    #[Groups(['camp:read'])]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Groups(['camp:read'])]
    private ?string $headerLogo = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Groups(['camp:read'])]
    private ?string $headerLogoMobile = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Groups(['camp:read'])]
    private ?string $programFilterImage = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['camp:read'])]
    private ?string $programLogo = null;

    // ... More Fields
    

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getHeaderLogo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->headerLogo;
    }

    public function setHeaderLogo(?string $headerLogo): self
    {
        $this->headerLogo = $headerLogo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getHeaderLogoMobile(): ?string
    {
        return $this->headerLogoMobile;
    }

    public function setHeaderLogoMobile(?string $headerLogoMobile): self
    {
        $this->headerLogoMobile = $headerLogoMobile;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProgramFilterImage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->programFilterImage;
    }

    public function setProgramFilterImage(?string $programFilterImage): self
    {
        $this->programFilterImage = $programFilterImage;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProgramLogo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->programLogo;
    }

    public function setProgramLogo(?string $programLogo): self
    {
        $this->programLogo = $programLogo;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Camp;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ImageField;

final class CampCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Camp::class;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        yield ImageField::new('headerLogo', 'field.logo.header')
            ->hideOnIndex()
            ->setRequired(false)
            ->setBasePath('uploads')
            ->setUploadDir('var/uploads/public')
            ->setUploadedFileNamePattern('[year]/[month]/[day]/[slug]-[contenthash].[extension]')
        ;
        yield ImageField::new('headerLogoMobile', 'field.logo.mobile_header')
            ->hideOnIndex()
            ->setRequired(false)
            ->setBasePath('uploads')
            ->setUploadDir('var/uploads/public')
            ->setUploadedFileNamePattern('[year]/[month]/[day]/[slug]-[contenthash].[extension]')
        ;
        yield ImageField::new('programLogo', 'field.logo.program')
            ->hideOnIndex()
            ->setRequired(false)
            ->setBasePath('uploads')
            ->setUploadDir('var/uploads/public')
            ->setUploadedFileNamePattern('[year]/[month]/[day]/[slug]-[contenthash].[extension]')
        ;
    }
}
```

Here is my `composer.json` if it helps.

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.2",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "api-platform/core": "^3.1",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.14",
        "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^4.7",
        "fresh/doctrine-enum-bundle": "^9.0",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.3",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.18",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.8",
        "symfony/asset": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/validator": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.3.*",
        "symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle": "^1.17",
        "webonyx/graphql-php": "^15.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "mtdowling/jmespath.php": "^2.6",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.48",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^6.3",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.3.*",
        "zenstruck/browser": "^1.4",
        "zenstruck/foundry": "^1.33"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```